# find -mtime returns wrong listing

Tags: linux

When I run this command:

```
root:/home/mws 0$ ls -lrt `find /home/data/ll_misc_logs/ -mtime +20`
```

And there are no files meeting the mtime setting, 20 days, it lists the contents of the current directory, /home/mws
Why?
Is there a way to just return nothing or a message?

Comment: Try posting to superuser or linux/unix

Answer (score 3):

When there are no files meeting the mtime setting, the output of `find ....` expands to ... nothing. In which case, your command becomes `ls -lrt`, which will always list the current directory.

If there aren't too many files on a typical run, this might work better:

```
find /home/data/ll_misc_logs -mtime +20 -print0 | xargs -0 -r ls -ltr
```

But, if you get so many files that `xargs` decides to split it into multiple invocations, it probably won't do exactly what you want, either.

Which leads me to... What exactly are you trying to do? On the surface, it looks like "show me the old files, in order by modification time", but it's likely part of something bigger that might be solved in a more efficient (and less error-prone) manner...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of files older than 20 days sorted by oldest first:

```
find /home/data/ll_misc_logs -mtime +20 -exec ls -l --time-style=%s {} \; | sort -n -k 6
```